# How can I inactivate the Duplicate Code rule? in a Different Modules and Different Source Files

Tags: c#, sonarqube

In our C # project we have cases of code duplication in different modules, since they have the same properties at the level of the entity layer, these properties are for example (code, name, consecutive). I have looked at the quality profile on the Sonarqube Server how to inactivate the quality rule only for this scenario.
[Our Sample Code Duplication Module A: Accounting and Module B: Financial Information (IFRS) - Option: Accounting Voucher.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHEhF.png)

Comment: Are you asking if you can change the code without editing the code? No is the answer to that...

Comment: I want to know how I can inactivate the rule in sonarqube, I was searching the server for the quality profile that we currently use, but there is no direct reference to a specific rule to obviate these scenarios when we declare properties with the same names in 2 or 3 Modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplication detection, i.e. copy-paste detection or CPD, can be either completely turned off by setting the following property:

```
sonar.cpd.exclusions=**/*.*
```

or you could exclude certain folders, or you could fine tune it using:

```
sonar.cpd.cs.minimumtokens=200
sonar.cpd.cs.minimumLines=100
```

You could find more info in [our documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters#AnalysisParameters-Duplications).